# Use a Shape to hide/unhide rows next to button location

Tags: excel, vba, button

I want a button that will hide the 2 rows below it. The idea is to create one button that can be copied to many locations and will hide the 2 rows below it.

I created a button that hides the 2 rows below it. But when I copy the button, all buttons hide/unhide the same rows. Not the rows relative to themselves. I have no idea why.

```vb
Sub ShowHideWeeksData()

    Dim addr As Object, rs As Long, cs As Long
'addr is the address of the button
'rs is the row number
'cs is the column number
Dim offset1 As Long
'offset for rows value
Dim offset2 As Long
'offset 2 for row value
Dim rs1 As Long
Dim rs2 As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim sheet As Worksheet
'rng is the cell the button is in

Set sheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")


Set addr = sheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
'address of the shape using the macro (i.e. the button)


'this part will figure out where the button I just clicked is

With addr.TopLeftCell
'coordinates of the top left cell of the button
rs = .Row
'row number of the button clicked
cs = .Column
'column number of button clicked
End With

offset1 = 1 'select 1 row below button
offset2 = 2 'select second row bellow button

rs1 = rs + offset1
rs2 = rs + offset2


With sheet
'the button defaults with the text hide this week, then if clicked it should hide the two rows
'if the rows are hidden then the text on the button will change to show this week and will show if clicked

    If .Shapes("HideWeekBtn").TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Show This Week" Then
        .Shapes("HideWeekBtn").TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Hide This Week"
        .Range(.Cells(rs1, cs), .Cells(rs2, cs)).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        .Shapes("HideWeekBtn").TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Show This Week"
        .Range(.Cells(rs1, cs), .Cells(rs2, cs)).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If


End With



End Sub
```

The expected results is I have a button in 3 locations

- in A4 then it hides rows 5&6
- in A7 then it hides rows 8&9
- in A10 then it hides rows 11&12

What happens currently is it only hides and unhides row 5 & 6 no matter which button I press

Comment: You have to give your buttons different names.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest working directly with the objects.
Try this:

```
Public Sub ShowHideWeeksData()
Const kShow As String = "Show This Week"
Const KHide As String = "Hide This Week"
Dim sp As Shape, rg As Range, blHide As Boolean
    Set sp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    With sp
        Set rg = .TopLeftCell.Offset(1).Resize(2)
        blHide = (.DrawingObject.Caption = KHide)
        rg.EntireRow.Hidden = blHide
        .DrawingObject.Caption = IIf(blHide, kShow, KHide)
    End With
    End Sub
```

Note: somehow this line `sp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text` did not work for me, therefore used this `sp.DrawingObject.Caption` instead.

Tested and all the copied `buttons` will point to the same `Procedure`, regardless of the name of each button.

Comment: thank you i'll try this. This coding thing is not my favorite thing